# Validating helm chart content

Tags: debugging, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am developing a chart and I had an error in it—incorrectly placed `imagePullSecrets` property. When I tried to install it via

```
helm install ./mychart
```

the misplaced element was simply ignored and I wondered what is wrong.

When I did

```
helm template ./mychart | kubectl apply --dry-run -f -
```

it instead printed:

```
error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0]): unknown field "imagePullSecrets" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container
```

which clearly shows what is wrong. I am not sure whether it matches what the tiller actually does with the expanded templates.

But if I just do a

```
helm install --dry-run --debug ./mychart
```

it just shows the expanded template and looks OK.

So how do I correctly verify all my templates match corresponding schemata with helm?

---

**Update:** Now that helm 3 has dispensed with tiller, any error messages returned by kubernetes during install or upgrade no longer get stuck there, but do make it to the helm output, **and** there is now a `--dry-run=server` option for `helm install` that solves this (to the extent it can be solved at all; some problems are not noticed even by kubernetes API until the resources are actually created).

Comment: This is an error from Kubernetes, not from Helm. Maybe [this doc entry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) could help you

Answer (score 26):

You can lint the chart by going `helm lint ./mychart` which should print the following if an issue is found:

```
$ helm lint ./mychart
==> Linting ./mychart
[ERROR] Chart.yaml: version is required
[INFO] Chart.yaml: icon is recommended

Error: 1 chart(s) linted, 1 chart(s) failed
```

See [helm lint](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-lint).

Comment: helm lint doesn't seem to do enough.  For example:
`helm lint chart/myProject` gives `1 chart(s) linted, no failures`, but `helm template chart/myProject/ | kubectl apply --dry-run -f -` gives
`error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "env" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Comment: Kubeval understands k8s manifest specs, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895342

Answer (score 18):

Use [kubeconform](https://github.com/yannh/kubeconform).

```
helm template ./mychart | kubeconform -strict
```

If you have CRDs you may need to use `kubeconform -ignore-missing-schemas`. I would recommend supplying the schema version: `kubeconform -kubernetes-version 1.18`.

A recommendation: specialise your charts and validate them. Examples follow.

Simple:

```sh
helm template --set some.key="val" | kubeconform -strict
```

Complex:

```sh
VALUES_FILE=$(cat << EOF
some:
  key: "val"

another:
  key:
    another: "val"
EOF
)
# It is important to quote "$VALUES_FILE" to ensure line breaks and indentation are preserved
echo "$VALUES_FILE" | helm template -f - | kubeconform -strict
```

Answer (score 6):

To avoid helm chart installation failure I suggest to follow the following sequence locally or/and in CI pipelines:

- run [helm lint](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_lint/). As the docs state:

> If the linter encounters things that will cause the chart to fail
> installation, it will emit [ERROR] messages.

- run [helm template](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/) for testing whether the chart can be rendered  locally successfully. While the installation can still fail once helm->kubernetes api server interaction happens, it still gives good quality check.
- validate that chart's Kubernetes manifests conform to Kubernetes schema using `kubeval` (doesn't support CRDs) or `kubeconform` (supports CRDs) after rendering the chart:

`helm template [chart_name] . | kubeval`

- run [helm unit tests](https://github.com/quintush/helm-unittest) for validating that the chart values are as expected (e.g. num of replicas is 1, volume is of type `hostPath`, etc..):

`helm unittest [chart_name] [chart_name]`

I summarized [how to test helm charts](https://www.rokpoto.com/test-helm-charts/) in my blog.

Answer (score 5):

I would high recommend using a **combination of the 2 solutions below**.

#### Solution 1

Using a [values.schema.json](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#schema-files)  for imposing a structure on the values.yaml file.

Example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "image": {
      "description": "Container Image",
      "properties": {
        "repo": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "tag": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    },
    "name": {
      "description": "Service name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "port": {
      "description": "Port",
      "minimum": 0,
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "protocol": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "protocol",
    "port"
  ],
  "title": "Values",
  "type": "object"
}
```

(!) This schema will be applied to the values to validate it. Validation occurs when any of the following commands are invoked:

```
helm install
helm upgrade
helm lint
helm template
```

In order to add conditions to the validation - read in [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#if-then-else).

(*) Further reading: [Nice article](https://austindewey.com/2020/06/13/helm-tricks-input-validation-with-values-schema-json/).

#### Solution 2

There are cases when the code in `values.schema.json` might be less readable when using conditions or we want to use a more dynamic logic into our validation.

In this case, we can create an `validations.yaml` file (some vendors prefer using a `.tpl` file) and add the validation logic using [go templates](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template).

Example:

If a specific feature (when enabled) needs an ip or a dns:

```
  some_feature:
    enabled: true
    ip:
    dns:
```

The validation logic can be written explicitly:

```
{{- if .Values.some_feature.enabled -}}
    {{- if and (not .Values.some_feature.ip ) (not .Values.some_feature.dns  ) -}}
        When some_feature is enabled, ip or dns must be given.
    {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

(*) This logic could also be writen using [json-schema if-else statement](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#if-then-else), but it might be less readable.

(**) Consider placing all validations under a `/tests` or `/validations` folder where all tests are devided into seperated files (like unit tests).

Comment: The question was primarily aimed at validating that the chart itself is implemented correctly, which this won't help with, but it still sure is a useful addition.